# 'open' is not recognized as an internal or external command while running project (npm start)

Tags: javascript

I have cloned this project from github [alt-tutorial](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt-tutorial)

while running the command npm start I am getting this error
[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question directly. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Also see [**Why not to upload Images of Code/Errors when asking a Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and for good measure What Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 9):

Please use `start` if you are using windows. `open` is a unix command so won't work in windows machines. for example if you have a command like below in a windows env:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && open index.html"
},
```

Use following instead:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && start index.html"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you clear the `npm` cache using following command and try again.

```
npm cache clean
```

Comment: Showing ERR! npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.

Comment: @AkashVishwakarma Try force cache cleaning by including --force